# Converting ConditionalExpression to Piecewise

Tags: functions, function-construction, piecewise

I have `Solve[]` return a list like `{{F->ConditionalExpression[EXPR1, 0<z<a1]},{F->ConditionalExpression[EXPR2, a1<z<a2]},...}` and so on -- `EXPR*` and `a1,a2,...` are somewhat complicated expressions, containing things like `Root[]`:

```
EQ = F^4 (138880 z + 318688 F z + 98415 F^10 z + 6561 F^9 (5 + 4 z) + 
    405 F^5 (625 + 1136 z) + 243 F^6 (-2500 + 5077 z)) == 
    1024 z + 11008 F z + 40192 F^2 z + 33536 F^3 z + 46944 F^6 z + 
    709776 F^7 z + 368388 F^8 z + 4374 F^12 (50 + 43 z) + 
    4374 F^11 (-125 + 202 z);

ftz = Solve[EQ && 0 < F < 1 && 0 < z < 1, F];
```

e.g. the first conditional:

```
In[100]:= N[(F /. ftz[[1]])]

Out[100]= ConditionalExpression[
 Root[-1024 z - 11008 z #1 - 40192 z #1^2 - 33536 z #1^3 + 
    138880 z #1^4 + 318688 z #1^5 - 46944 z #1^6 - 709776 z #1^7 - 
    368388 z #1^8 + (253125 + 460080 z) #1^9 + (-607500 + 
       1233711 z) #1^10 + (546750 - 883548 z) #1^11 + (-218700 - 
       188082 z) #1^12 + (32805 + 26244 z) #1^13 + 98415 z #1^14 &, 
  2], 0. < z < 0.674139]
```

I need to (numerically) integrate this function for given parameter values, which Mathematica refuses to do. However, if I convert the expression into a Piecewise function: for example as

```
ff = Piecewise[{{ftz[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]], ftz[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]]},
    {ftz[[2]][[1]][[2]][[1]], ftz[[2]][[1]][[2]][[2]]},
    {0, z == 0},
    {1, z == 1}}];
```

it easily computes the integral. Unfortunately, the number of intervals and the breakpoints are parameter dependent, and this must be done automatically as the function is called inside another function.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convert such a list of conditionals into a Piecewise function, or how to otherwise compute the integral? Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question, however it is not clear what is the function, what are parameters, what is your expected `Piecewise` form etc.  More details are needed to give a constructive answer. `ConditionalExpression` is new in `M8` and I suspect it is not quite seamlessly integrated with the rest of the system.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example equation. Unfortunately I do not have an earlier version of Mathematica installed to see what Solve returns there :(

Comment: By the way, when multiple indexing, you can use a single call to `Part`. It'll be more efficient and neater. `x[[1]][[2]]==x[[1, 2]]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That conversion is straightforward, in this case. It is a one-liner

```
Piecewise[List @@@ Flatten[N@ftz][[All, 2]] ]
```

Now let me explain. As you have noticed, `Solve` returns solutions of the form:

```
{ {_ -> _}, {_ -> _}, ...}
```

which is what `Flatten` reduces to

```
{_ -> _, _ -> _, ...}
```

Then, I take only the right hand side of each `Rule` via `Flatten[...][[All,2]]` leaving us with something of the form

```
{ConditionalExpression[...], ...}
```

So, we need to replace `ConditionalExpression` with `List` to make it palatable to `Piecewise`, and the it is done using the shorthand form of [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) at level 1, `@@@`. Finally, we feed the result into `Piecewise` and get what you want.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the simpler form

```
Piecewise[List @@@ Last @@@ N@ftz]
```

works just as well.

Comment: (+1) could also apply `Apply` twice: `Piecewise[List @@@ Last @@@ N@ftz]` or `List @@@ Last @@@ N@ftz // Piecewise `:)

Comment: @kguler updated my answer with that form.

Answer (score 5):

It may not always be appropriate to convert a ConditionalExpression into Piecewise, because the two are not equivalent, and you may be changing the meaning. This is because Piecewise IMPOSES a default value of 0 if the conditions are not satisfied, whereas ConditionalExpression leaves the expression as undefined.

For example, given:

```
In[1]:=  expr = ConditionalExpression[1, x > 3]

In[2]:=  Simplify[expr, x < -2]
Out[2]=  Undefined
```

whereas:

```
In[3]:=  Simplify[Piecewise[{{1, x > 3}}],  x < -2]
Out[3]=  0
```

But, if you do want to impose the swap, say given:

```
In[4]:=  sol = Integrate[x^n, {x, 0, 1}]
Out[4]=  ConditionalExpression[1/(1 + n), Re[n] > -1]
```

... then an easy way to do it is:

```
In[5]:=  sol /. ConditionalExpression[xx_, yy_] :> Piecewise[{{xx, yy}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, you can set the default value of `Piecewise[]` to be `Undefined`: `Piecewise[{{1/(1 + n), Re[n] > -1}}, Undefined]`