# Conditional Output of Solve as a piecewise function

Tags: core-language

I am solving a set of equations, and Solve gives me (as expected) conditional assignment rules. Now I would like to define a piecewise function with that output, and use both the solutions and the conditions of the output, as a piecewise-defined function. Is there an easy way to do that?

Here is a toy example, from Solve I get as expected following conditional output:

```
{{p1 -> ConditionalExpression[2r, r < 1], 
  p2 -> ConditionalExpression[4r, r < 1]},
 {p1 -> ConditionalExpression[-2r, r > 1], 
  p2 -> ConditionalExpression[-4r, r > 1]}}
```

And I would like to construct piecewise functions
p1[r_], p2[r_] as defined above.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing with using `Piecewise`?

Comment: Well I cant use the format of the output assignment rules

Comment: Can you, please, write a concrete minimal example for demonstration purposes?

Comment: That can not work because the condition for both branches are the same. Therefore you do not need a piecewise function, but a function that returns a vector of 2 results.

Comment: I changed the example

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/converting-conditionalexpression-to-piecewise to this end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
solution = {{p1 -> ConditionalExpression[2 r, r < 1], 
    p2 -> ConditionalExpression[4 r, r < 1]}, 
   {p1 -> ConditionalExpression[-2 r, r > 1], 
    p2 -> ConditionalExpression[-4 r, r > 1]}};

{pw1, pw2} = # /. solution & /@ {p1, p2} /. 
   ce : {__ConditionalExpression} :> Piecewise[List @@@ ce]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Values @ Transpose[solution] /. 
    ce : {__ConditionalExpression} :> Piecewise[List @@@ ce]
```

[image]

Additional alternatives using `Merge` and `GroupBy`:

```
ClearAll[toPiecewise1]
toPiecewise = Normal @* Map[Piecewise[List @@@ #] &] @* Merge[Identity];

toPiecewise1 @ solution
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[toPiecewise2]
toPiecewise2 = Normal @ GroupBy[Join @@ #, First -> Last, Piecewise[List @@@ #] &]&;

toPiecewise2 @ solution
```

[image]

Comment: Great, It works perfectly, I but I will need some time to understand the magic :)